# How to make use of react-select props typings

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am trying to write a component that wraps the `AsyncSelect`, however in this case their typings for props have a generic and I'm not sure how to implement this.

Here is my code:

```
export class PipTagSelect extends React.Component<AsyncProps> {
    constructor(props:AsyncProps ) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AsyncSelect
                isMulti
                cacheOptions
                {...this.props}
            />
        );
     }
}
```

The compiler gives the error `AsyncProps<OptionType>` requires one type argument. This makes sense when looking at the type definitions.

However I've never had to provide a type argument to props when wrapping a component. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your class as generic

```
 export class<T> PipTagSelect extends React.Component<AsyncProps<T>> {
    constructor(props:AsyncProps<T>) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AsyncSelect
                isMulti
                cacheOptions
                {...this.props}
            />
        );
     }
 }
```

check this out [on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3960#issuecomment-165335501)